# Google Analytics Query for Rank Change

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a Google Analytics query that list ranking of pages without having to do extensive data wrangeling?

Right now I'm using this:

```
  "query": {
    "dimensions": ["ga:hostname","ga:date"],
    "metrics": ["ga:sessions"],
    "start-date": "2daysAgo",
    "end-date": "yesterday",
    "sort": "ga:date,-ga:sessions",
    "max-results": "10000",
    "filters": ["ga:sessions>2000"]
  },
```

Comment: what are you trying to rank the pages by?  If its sessions, it maybe because you have ga:date in your sort field

Answer (score 1):

The sort field ranks the pages by the metric you include.  What looks to be happening in your example is that you are sorting by ga:date, then ga:sessions, which would give perhaps undesired results.

Try this modification:

```
"query": {
  "dimensions": ["ga:hostname","ga:date"],
  "metrics": ["ga:sessions"],
  "start-date": "2daysAgo",
  "end-date": "yesterday",
  "sort": "-ga:sessions",
  "max-results": "10000",
  "filters": ["ga:sessions>2000"]
},
```